# Django + Google App Engine, problem updating existent entry

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am having trouble with updating saved instance in datastore.

My form has two fields — `title` (optional) and `content`.
What I want to do is to set `title` field value to `Post # id_of_just_created_post`.

So I am checking `form.instance.title is None` and then want to update this instance's `title`:

```
…
form.save()
id = form.instance.key().id()

if form.instance.title is None:
    form.instance.title = "Post # %s" % str(id)
    form.save()
…
```

But again, I am getting `None` as value.

Where is my error with update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
inst = form.save()

if not inst.title:
    inst.title = "Post # %s" % inst.pk
    inst.save()
```

Comment: Although I'm using `inst.key().id()` instead of `inst.pk`.